# error in printing the variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visual-web-developer

When I'm running this code it is not showing me the message which I want to display (i.e: res).Suppose I'm giving an input "`$code$".Can anyone just help me out?`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter a sample message</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
        <button onclick="parse()">submit</button>
        <p id="a"></p>
    </form>
    <script>
        function parse(){
            var msg=document.getElementById("a").innerHTML;
            var res=msg.replace("$code$","1101"); 
            document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=res;//this is to print res.

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two elements can't have the same ID. Further, an `input` element's value can not be obtained using the `innerHTML` property. Also, on clicking the submit button, the page will reload since the form get's submitted. To prevent that, call the function `parse` in an `onsubmit` on the `<form>` tag, and return false from the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter a sample message</h1>
    <form onsubmit="return parse();">
        <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
        <p id="b"></p>
    </form>
    <script>
        function parse(){
            var msg = document.getElementById("a").value;
            document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = msg;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="a" class="input_field" id="a">
    <button type="button" onclick="parse()">submit</button>
    <p id="a"></p>
</form>
<script>
    function parse(){
        var msg=document.getElementById("a").innerHTML;
        var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]
        msg = form.getElementsByClassName("input_field")[0].value;//this is to print res.

    }
</script>
```

I added type="button"  to the button to prevent the form from reloading the page